# Excel Source Workbook not updating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a file that contains daily timesheets for each day of the week and a single weekly timesheet. I have the formula set up so when a daily timesheet is changed the weekly automatically updates. It was working perfect expect this folder that contains both files is considered my 'master' blank copy. My hope was to copy the master every week and rename it for the week since I have to do this every week. When I make a copy of the master and adjust the copied daily timesheet it doesnt change the new master copy. The formula is still linking to the original file which is blank and not the new copy. Is there a way for my formula to automatically update the new pathway when I copy the entire master?

its currently this in the weekly when copied :

='Z:\Payroll**Master**\Monday[weekly.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$10

but I need this: ='Z:\Jobs\Payroll**WE03 30 2021**\Monday[weekly.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$10

Answer (score 0):

I've found it easier, in many cases, to do the following:

copy the sheet to a new workbook
activate the new sheet in the new workbook
select all (Ctrl+A)
do a find/replace on
find: master
replace: <new folder when copied, in this case> 'WE03 30 2021'
replace all